# Unable to get the CrossListQueryCache in Foreach to loop the list item

Tags: ssom, crosslistqueryinfo, crosslistquerycache

I had used CrossListQueryInfo to get the large amount of items from lists.
When I am trying to use the object of CrossListQueryCache I am facing below error.

Can anyone help me what's the issue and why I am unable to call the object of
CrossListQueryCache

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate using `DataRow` inside a Datatable.

You cannot use `SPListItem` to iterate inside a datatable as its incorrect.

The object model to use Datatable is `DataTable -> DataRowCollection -> DataRow` where you use the DataRow to look for contents inside a column of a row

Code would be somewhat as below:

```
foreach(DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    //if you want to use column name, try the below line of code.
    var title = Convert.ToString(row["Title"]);

    //if you want to use index, try the below line of code.
    //var title = Convert.ToString(row[0]); 
}
```